# gomobile build, the Paho mqtt client cannot connect to mqtt broker in APK

Tags: apk, mqtt, paho, gomobile, gomobile-android

I am working on a project where I need to use [gomobile tool](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile) to create an Android app.
The sample code I have in Go is as below

```
    var broker = "127.0.0.1"
    //var broker = "broker.mqttdashboard.com"
    var port = 1883
    opts := mqtt.NewClientOptions()
    opts.AddBroker(fmt.Sprintf("tcp://%s:%d", broker, port))
    opts.SetClientID("go_mqtt_client")
    opts.SetConnectionLostHandler(connectLostHandler) // define what to do when connection is lost
    client := mqtt.NewClient(opts)
    tokenClient := client.Connect()
    if tokenClient.Wait() && tokenClient.Error() != nil {
        panic(tokenClient.Error())
    }
    ...
```

When I bind this code using **"gomobile bind"**, generating the Golang plugin and calling them inside the android project there is no issue.
Connections is satisfied and I can verify  the local mqtt broker (mosquitto) and the mqtt client app are communicating as well.

But when I generate the APK file using **"gomobile build -target=android"**, the connect function generates and error.
To be able to test the logs i used a public broker instead of the local mqtt broker. I replaced the

> var broker = "127.0.0.1"

by the HiveMQ public broker address (I have already validated the public broker functionality)

> var broker = "broker.mqttdashboard.com"

It seems like there is an issue with connecting from mqtt client app to mqtt broker. Here is the exact error message I found in logs:

> E/Go: panic: network Error : dial tcp: lookup
> broker.mqttdashboard.com: No address associated with hostname
> goroutine 11 [running]: E/GoLog: panic: network Error : dial tcp: lookup broker.mqttdashboard.com: No address associated with hostname
> E/Go: main.starting()

This is generated by **"panic(tokenClient.Error())"** part in my code.

Any idea why the connection is not settled using "gomobile build", while it is working when I use "gomobile bind" ?

Comment: This error will be generated by a [call to `net.DialTimeout` within the library](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/master/netconn.go#L46). Try connecting directly with `net.DialTimeout("tcp", "broker.mqttdashboard.com", time.Minute)` (I'd expect that to fail with the same error). I suspect this may be a permissions error (see the comments re [`AndroidManifest.xml` here](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/mobile/example/network)).

Comment: @Brits Thanks for your comment.
You on right, It is actually the permission. I just fixed it couple of hours ago by adding the AndoridManifest.xml file in my go project and adding the permission. I will reply to my post when i realize what permission was required.
Its amazing i got the idea from the same [example](https://github.com/golang/mobile/tree/master/example/network) as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I could fix the issue.

1. I added the AndoridManifest.xml file to the same directory that the main go package is.
2. Added the following line in between the manifest tags (<manifest> )

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">